# decrease distance between bottomBorder and text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

As an underline, I have added borderBottom to a view that is wrapped around my text element. However, the bottom is a bit lower than how I want it to be. Is there any way I can reduce the distance?

```
          <View
            style={[
              styles.textContainer,
              selected === index ? styles.selectedTab : null,
            ]}>
            <Text style={styles.tabText}>{item.text}</Text>
          </View>
```

```
  selectedTab: {
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
  }
```

Codesandbox:
You'll see the underline when you click on one of the text items.
https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/shallow-watermelon

Comment: You can lower the paddingBottom of  tabText style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have

```
  tabText: {
    color: 'black',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
```

You can decrease `paddingBottom` to achieve what you want